# junit test for @ControllerAdvice in spring boot

Tags: java, junit, spring-batch, spring-boot-test

I am trying to test my `RestController` for validation. This is my `controller`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/my-data",method=RequestMethod.GET, produces= {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<?> doSomething(@Validated @RequestParam (value = "id")@Size(min=6,max=6) String id){

    //some logic here
}
```

I have a `ControllerAdvice` to handle `ConstraintViolationException`

```
    @ExceptionHandler({ ConstraintViolationException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleConstraintViolation(ConstraintViolationException ex, WebRequest request) {

        //exception handling here
return  ResponseEntity.status(400).body("My error Message here");

    }
```

Everything is good. But Now i am trying to write unit test case but my unit test case never throws `ConstraintViolationException` .

i am setting up `MockMvc` as below

```
mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).setControllerAdvice(new MyControllerAdviceClass()).build();
```

And test case as

```
@Test
public void testForConstrain() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(get("/my-data")
            .param("id", "123"))
    .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
}
```

But this test case is not passing as `ConstraintViolationException` is not thrown. Not sure what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Standalone MockMvc misses lots of infrastructure components such as error handlers and request processors; I strongly recommend using the real context precisely for this reason.

Comment: I understand what i miss by not using `@SpringBootTest` or `@WebMvcTest` but this is legacy code and i don't want to spend time refactoring all test cases.